# Как сделать маршрут к другому хосту через LINUX машину

Tags: linux, windows, маршрутизация, vpn, локальная-сеть

У меня такая проблема:

Компьютер ->     роутер         -> компьютер с LINUX          ->   удаленный хост

192.168.0.166 -> 192.168.0.1  ->  (192.168.0.200  192.168.1.200)   ->    192.168.1.2

Мне нужно соединиться между компьютером 192.168.0.166  и  192.168.1.2 через компьютер с LINUX

Компьютер с LINUX имеет два сетевых интерфейса и видит оба компьютера 192.168.0.166 и 192.168.1.2

Также компьютер с LINUX подключен к VPN и имеет адрес 10.0.8.13.

Мне нужно связываться с одним удаленным хостом 192.168.1.2 через компьютер с LINUX.

Компьютер с LINUX имеет два сетевых интерфейса 192.168.0.200 (подключен к роутеру) 192.168.1.200 (подключен к удаленному хосту) и адрес VPN 10.0.8.252 все адреса постоянные, статические, **IP Forwarding включен.**

Доступ к компьютеру с LINUX есть со всех компьютеров в сети.

Но компьютеры из VPN сети и внутри сети видят только компьютер с LINUX а с удаленным хостом нельзя связаться, нет пинга.

Я понимаю, что нужно добавить маршруты, но не знаю как это сделать, читал как сделать простые маршруты но с таким для меня еще сложно, я еще не понимаю.

[image: Схема сети]

Маршруты на компьютере с LINUX:

```
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 wlan0
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
    0.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 tun0
    10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 tun0
    192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 wlan0
    192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1      0        0 wlan0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Маршруты на компьютере с WINDOWS:

```
    IPv4 таблица маршрута
    ===========================================================================
    Активные маршруты:
    Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс          Метрика
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.166     55
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
          192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.166    311
        192.168.0.166  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.166    311
        192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.166    311
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.166    311
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.166    311
    ===========================================================================
    Постоянные маршруты:
      Отсутствует
```

Comment: Если forwarding включен, то всё должно работать. Проблема у вас в VPN, который сбивает настройки. Либо я не понимаю схемы. Приведите выводы `ip route show` с каждой машины (OK, `ipconfig /all` на Windows, если я не ошибаюсь).

Comment: на каджом хосте должен быть маршрут каждого узла

Comment: Я добавил таблицы маршрутов. На данный момент я подключаюсь не через VPN а локально и у меня нет пинга на удаленный компьютер (192.168.1.2) с компьютера WINDOWS (192.168.0.166). С компьютера  WINDOWS (192.168.0.166) есть пинг до компьютера LINUX (192.168.0.200). А с компьютера LINUX есть пинг и на удаленный комп и на локальный, то есть везде. Но мне нужно чтобы через него пакеты шли, я на нем работать не буду.

Comment: На данный момент я не использую VPN, тут хотябы по локальной сети добраться до удаленного компьютера. Мне нужен всего один TCP порт 61000. На удаленной машине работает TCP сервер и отвечает на запросы по 61000 порту.

Comment: @Роман, в синтаксисе iproute2 добавление маршрута на `192.168.0.166` до  подсети `192.168.1.0/24` (и до хоста `192.168.1.2` в частности) выглядело бы как-то так: `ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.200`, как это прописывается в win — на вскидку не скажу. Также если для `192.168.1.2` машина с linux не является шлюзом по умолчанию, то нужно на ней прописать симметричный маршрут до `192.168.0.0/24` — иначе хост не будет знать, куда отправлять ответ на пинг, а также не забудь включить  перенаправление пакенов (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`) на машине с linux.